# Riley Riddle #5: Goes well with peanut

Tags: riddle

Start with a vote for the Chancellor.
End with the studies before doctor.
The middle is fed by Kuremaa.
Interference says "Mea culpa!"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you

> Jammed? (If so I'm so sorry)

Start with a vote for the Chancellor.

> The Chancellor is German, so that's a JA.

End with the studies before doctor.

> This would be MED school.

The middle is fed by Kuremaa.

> Lake Kuremaa, in Estonia feeds the AMME River.

Interference says "Mea culpa!"

> Interference says I'm guilty because it JAMMED you!

Also the title

> JAM(med) goes well with peanut butter.

Comment: Why would I be jammed?

Comment: @flashstorm Well I'm not going to tell you to eat your veggies ;P (also, please see explanations above)